# How can I attach an event handler to a Button in a DataGridTemplateColumn defined in XAML, in PowerShell?

Tags: wpf, xaml, powershell, datagrid, powershell-4.0

I have some XAML I'm importing into a PowerShell script.  It contains a `DataGrid` which displays the result of a PowerShell cmdlet.  I've added an 'Edit' button to each row using a `DataGridTemplateColumn`.  Now, I'd like to add an event handler to each button.  I can do it in code:

```
$adUsersList_Results = $activeDirectory_Users_ListControl.FindName('ResultsDataGrid')
$dataTemplate = New-Object 'Windows.DataTemplate'
$buttonElement = New-Object 'Windows.FrameworkElementFactory' ([Windows.Controls.Button])
$buttonElement.SetValue([Windows.Controls.Button]::ContentProperty, "Edit")
$buttonElement.AddHandler([Windows.Controls.Button]::ClickEvent, [Windows.RoutedEventHandler]{
    PARAM (
        [Object]$sender,
        [Windows.RoutedEventArgs]$e
    )
    Write-Host "Clickety-click!"
    Write-Host $sender.DataContext
})
$dataTemplate.VisualTree = $buttonElement
$dataGridTemplateColumn = New-Object 'Windows.Controls.DataGridTemplateColumn'
$dataGridTemplateColumn.Header = 'Poo'
$dataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate = $dataTemplate
$adUsersList_Results.Columns.Add($dataGridTemplateColumn)
```

but it's a bit unwieldy.  The XAML looks like this:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
          x:Name="ResultsDataGrid"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          Margin="3"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Button Content="Edit" Width="60" x:Name="ADUserListButton"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I've tried using FindName('ADUserListButton') but it doesn't work.  Is there a way to keep all of the visual stuff in XAML and just do the event handler in the PowerShell?

**Aside**: I'm aware of Show-UI.  I'm actually doing the same thing in Show-UI and in PowerShell & XAML before deciding which is the best fit for us.

I'm also aware that you can do editing in-grid but I don't think it's a great user-experience for this type of data.

Comment: The answer here is working for me [Handle the attached ButtonBase.Click event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71024960/890492)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure but could it be because the XAML button you list doesn't have the handler connection to it?  i.e.

```
<Button Content="Edit" Width="60" x:Name="ADUserListButton" Click="ADUserListButton_Click"/>
```

Comment: As far as I understand it, ADUserListButton_Click would have to be an event handler in the code-behind file.  When using dynamic XAML in PowerShell, there isn't a code-behind file.  Instead, you wire up the event handler as you would if you were doing it in code, in the code-behind, except that you have to call the Add_Click method on the control, rather than using the += syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done that with powershell but if it was in the .cs code-behind file of a usercontrol for instance you could try GetTemplateChild("your control name").

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of calling button inside data-grid using Powershell, hope this helps.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

Function Check-Event($ev,$co,$da){
$comp=$co.trim()
$re = Get-EventLog Application -ComputerName "$comp" -InstanceId $ev -After $da
$res.Text += "There are "+$re.count+" events pf EventID $ev on Computer $Comp after the time $da ch"
}

[Xml]$Form = @"
  <Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="151" Margin="112,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="279"/>
        <Button Name="ADUserListButton" Content="Edit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="140,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <TextBox Name="Result" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="140,124,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="Hello World"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

"@

$NR=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $Form)
$Win=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $NR )

$Start = $Win.FindName("ADUserListButton")
$res = $Win.FindName("Result")

$Start.Add_Click({
$event=$res.text
If($event -eq "") {
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Please make sure all values are entered", "Missing Values")} 
Else{Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select username -OutVariable a
$name=$a.username
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("User name is $name", "Hello")
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have done with my grid clicks where lots of data is listed, rather than creating code for each cell, you can create a click handler on the datagrid that gets the selected row or cell and does something with it.

```
$adUsersList_Results = $activeDirectory_Users_ListControl.FindName('ResultsDataGrid')
$adUsersList.Add_Click({
  $sender = $args[0]
  $e      = $args[1]
  $prop = $sender.SelectedItem.<#[Some property of the row]#>
  #do something with $prop....
})
```

Don't know if this is what you are looking for, and I know it is a little bit late, but it might help someone else out there...