# Powershell with XAML: Handle click event of button inside ListBox datatemplate

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

I have created a XAML document that contains a listbox.  The DataTemplate for the ListBox.ItemTemplate contains a TextBlock and a Button (ommitting irrelevant properties for brevity)

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text={Binding AppName} />
    <Button Name="btnRefresh" Content="Refresh"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I am displaying and handling this XAML with Powershell.  Is there a way to add a click event to the button from Powershell as the controls in the DataTemplate do not get enumerated when I read in the XAML, so I cannot simply reference the variable and append an Add_Click handler to it:

```
$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
$window.FindName("btnRefresh").add_click({...
```

So on clicking the button i'd then need determine which button has been clicked if there are many rows in the ListBox.  Ideally the EventArgs for the click event would pass some data pertaining to the ListBoxItem to which the button is attached.

Just re-iterating that any solutions must be for Powershell, not C#.

Thanks

Comment: The Button instance is accessible via the sender argument of the Click event handler. The DataContext property of the Buttons holds a reference to the associated item.

Comment: Thanks.  That will help me get the event data.  I've edited the question as there is an earlier issue that remains, namely how to I add a click event to a button in a ListBox DataTemplate using Powershell.

Comment: You would usually not do that at all. Instead, bind the Button's Command property to an ICommand in the item class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add an event handler to the `Button` in the `ItemTemplate`. You could handle the attached `ButtonBase.Click` event of the `ListBox` itself, e.g.:

```
$listBox.AddHandler([System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase]::ClickEvent, 
    $ClickHandler)
```

In the handler you could then get a reference to the clicked button using the `OriginalSource` property of the `RoutedEventArgs`.

Comment: This looks (a lot) simpler than my current approach.  In this instance, what is $ClickHandler referring to?  Is it a variable holding some kind of Lambda function?

Comment: You are a legend!

[System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler]$ClickHandler = {
    Write-Host $_.source.OriginalSource
}